# Coordinates change unit vectors problem

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Let an $x´,y´,z´$ coordinate system be obtained by rotating an xyz-coordinate system about the z-axis through an angle of $-45^\circ$.
if **i** , **j** and **k** are the standard unit vectors in $xyz$-system the components of these vectors in the $x´,y´,z´$-system are:

**i**$=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$
**j**=$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)$
**k**=$(0,0,1)$

What is the relationship between $\sqrt{2}$ and $45^\circ$?

Why divide 1 by $\sqrt{2}$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the cosine and sine of the angle:

$$ \cos(45^\circ) = \sin(45^\circ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

This may be more evident if you convert to radians, $ 45^\circ = \frac{\pi}{4} \text{ rad}$.